# How many ways can I sort 50 distinct items into 2 lists with no repetition, order matters?

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

I must use all $50$ items, but either list can be empty.

I know that the default answer is $2^k$ for $k$ elements when order does not matter. However, I am not sure how to arrive at the answer when order does matter. (As an aside: if there were three lists, would it be $3^k$ if order did not matter?)

I have attempted to break down the problem in the title as $3$ items into $2$ lists. The total number of combinations is $24$, but I am still unsure of how to extrapolate that number into a more general form. I have looked into a "stars and bars" solution but that doesn't give me $24$ either.

The answer appears to be $4!$ for $3$ items, but I have only vague ideas as to why. Appealing to the multiplication principle with repetitions forbidden, I proposed that we have $4$ boxes, where the first box can be either the first, second, third, or none of the items. Is this the correct way to think about it? If so, is $51!$ the answer when there are $50$ items?

Comment: 1. Can a list be empty? 2. Are the lists themselves distinct? If the answer to both questions is Yes, then $50!\cdot51$. If the answer to the first question is No, then change $51$ to $49$. If the answer to the second question is No, then divide the result by $2!$.

Comment: As I wrote in the OP, they can be empty. I am unsure what you mean by distinct, but whether or not they can be distinguished is not specified. Does the answer change if the objects themselves are different? We cannot repeat items and order matters, so that doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: By distinct, I mean, for example, that $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\}\}\neq\{\{3,4,5\}\},\{1,2\}\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes. They are distinct. But I am more concerned with the reasoning behind $50!*51$ as opposed to the answer itself.

Comment: So you have $50$ permutations and $51$ places to put a delimiter (separating each permutation into $2$ lists). Hence the answer is $50!\cdot51=51!$.

Answer (score 4):

How many ways can you arrange 51 objects?  The 50 items, plus a divider that splits the items into two lists?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have $0 \leq n \leq 50$ items on the first list.

First, choose which $n$ items you want on the list ($_{50}C_n$ possibilities).  Then choose what order you want them in ($n!$ possibilities).

You've already chosen what goes on the other list (both how many, and which ones).  So, choose the order of those items on the other list ($(50-n)!$ possibilities).

Then, the magic happens when we sum over $n$:

$$N = \sum_{n=0}^{50}\frac{50!}{n!(50-n)!}n!(50-n)! = \sum_{n=0}^{50}50! = 51 \cdot 50! = 51!.$$